# Profiling spark executor memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, profiling

I have been wanting to find a good way to profile a spark application's executor when its run from a jupyter notebook interface. I basically want to see details like what is the heap memory usage, young  and perm gen memory usage etc through time for a particular executor(ones that fail atleast).

I see many solutions out there but nothing that seems mature and easy to install/use.

Are there any good tools that let me do this easily?